# How to obtain the File.getParent() for the File that was instantiated by setting just filename in the working directory?

Tags: java, java-io

If I have instantiated a file with full path like

```
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(new URI("file:/C:/java2018/infa2019_2sm/test.txt"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it is possible to call later

```
   File directory = file.getParentFile();
```

and it will be assigned to the C:/java2018/infa2019_2sm directory

But if we instantiate the file with just filename of the existing file in the working directory, like this

```
   File file=new File("test.txt");
```

every getters of the file work except the getParentFile(), getParentFile() returns null.

So what is the legal way to get guaranteed directory of the File object with instantiating it with both full path and short path relative to the working directory? Is it ever possible with java.io or I need to use java.nio anyway?

Windows 10, if matters, but of course I'd like to have it cross-platform.

Comment: If nothing else works, then use a workaround `new File(file.getAbsolutePath()).getParent()`

Comment: if it returns null, just get the working dir (as it must be in there):  System.getProperty("user.dir");

Comment: @aran I don't like deal with only full path or only user.dir inside the code, that's why I'm asking, as i'l like this path being passed as flexible parameter and to make it executable anyway.

Comment: @Tom File directory=new File(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()).getParent()); worked for me

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev just for the fun, getAbsolutePath uses "user.dir". Tom's answer is the good one thou, as I agree with you about dirty user.dirs inside code

Comment: @aran, got it. I just wanted to avoid any "ifs" in my code but not in the called by my code :)

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev ops, get you know. Need some more coffee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @Tom's answer the working way looks like

```
   File directory=new File(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()).getParent());
```